# SKPhysics turn off isDynamic after it reaches a certain position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

How can I go about approaching this? I want to turn off isDyanmic after my sprite has approached a certain position. So basically how do I do something after something has occurred in swift?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: trying to make it fall into an exact location

Comment: .... you are going to need to explain your problem better,  turning off isDynamic may not be the answer at all

Comment: You do something simply by doing it. What's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func update(_      currentTime: TimeInterval) {
     //In this case, you can just      change self.size.height/2 with whatever position you want.
     if sprite.position.y <=      self.size.height/

    sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false


}


 }
```

This should do the trick. In this case, the sprite is falling from on top. Once it reaches the middle, it becomes static.

Comment: `isDynamic = false` means `affectedByGravity` gets ignored

Comment: Very True. Answer has been Edited.